# How do I, or can I use a static resource for the StringFormat on a TextBlock?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting

I have a text block that is displaying the date/time.  The look of the clock may be different on some controls in the application, as far as color and maybe font, but I want the date and time to have the same format.

I know I can set the StringFormat property like so:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentDateTime, StringFormat='{}{0:h\:mm tt}'}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Proxima Nova Rg" FontSize="20" />
```

However, I don't know how to pull the string format out into a separate string resource dictionary.  I tried to do something like the following, but the date time string didn't appear at all.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <system:String x:Key="MyFormat">{}{0:h\:mm tt}</system:String>
</ResourceDictionary>

<!-- In another file -->
<TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentDateTime, StringFormat={StaticResource MyFormat}}" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Proxima Nova Rg" FontSize="20" />
```

Can this be done at all?  If so, how?

Thanks

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It appears you just have to remove the `{}`:

```
<system:String x:Key="MyFormat">{0:h\:mm tt}</system:String>
```

The `{}` is required for attribute values to prevent them from being interpreted as a markup extension. However, with property element syntax, you no longer need the `{}` because curly braces do not have special meaning in that context.

Comment: Good question, great answer, never knew how to do this.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.  I'm surprised that I couldn't find a question about this on SO.  Maybe I missed it.